# Find path of compiled app in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-compiler

I'm compiling my app was deisgined by app desginer (MATLAB R2016b). I added some extra files in this part of compiler:

[image]

In my codes I used `ctfroot` to find path after compile but when I use my compiled GUI and I want open one of these files from GUI there is difference between two paths.

```
Real path:
C:\Users\myY\AppData\Local\Temp\my_user\mcrCache9.1\Main_a4\Main_app_r20

Returned path by `ctfroot` function:
C:\Users\myY\AppData\Local\Temp\my_user\mcrCache9.1\Main_a4\
```

`Main_app_r20` folder name is constant in every use of GUI and in every computer?

Comment: Why can't you do `fullfile(ctfroot, 'Main_app_r20', 'vba_size_2_in.txt')`?

Comment: @Suever  I didn't create `Main_app_r20` folder. It was created by MATLAB!. What is this folder? Is it constant in every use of GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not want the `exe` directory?  i.e. the location (usually in program files) where the exe is located, that's where your other required files would (normally) be located.

This is what I do in my deployed applications to get the exe folder:

```
  [status, result] = system('path');
  installpath = char(regexpi(result, 'Path=(.*?);', 'tokens', 'once'));
```